# Skipped x frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. What does this error signify and how to solve this?

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to do authentication with firbase in my Flutter app. Once the user is signed in and goes to the Authenticted screen, this error shows up.
I'm using google_signin plugin with simple logics.

```
    bool isAuth = false;

  //check if the user is signed in
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    googleSignIn.onCurrentUserChanged.listen((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }, onError: (err) {
      print("Error signing in: $err");
    });
    //maintain the signin
    googleSignIn.signInSilently(suppressErrors: false).then((account) {
      handleSignIn(account);
    }).catchError((err) {
      print("Error signing in: $err");
    });
  }

  handleSignIn(GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (account != null) {
      print('User signed in!: $account');
      setState(() {
        isAuth = true;
      });
    } else {
      setState(() {
        isAuth = false;
      });
    }
  }

  //sign in using google
  login() {
    googleSignIn.signIn();
  }

  logout() {
    googleSignIn.signOut();
  }

  Widget buildAuthScreen() {
    return Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text("LogOut"),
        onPressed: logout(),
      ),
    );
  }
```

then the unauth screen has basic login layout for signining in...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you are not doing anything unnecessary in your `main`, you can just ignore it.

the number of skipped frames is dependent on:

- The number of static and top-level variables that need initiation on startup.
- Speed of the CPU that will be doing computational work, like parsing JSONs at startup.
- Speed of the device storage for initiating databases and shared preferences.
- Whether you're using a debug or release build of your app.
- The speed of the network connection in case of needing some necessary data before the app starts up.
- Whether you're using an emulator or a physical device.
- The size of the widget tree in your home page.

Comment: What is the time complexity of a static variable? In my application on main class, I am defining 8 static variables. Because of that application is slowing down or any other reason?

Comment: I don't think 8 static variables will have any meaningful effect. The most likely cause of a slowdown is having an expansive widget tree. widgets like `Stack` & `Opacity`. another cause could be the usage of widgets that are built using normal functions. because of how flutter works, building widgets using classes is going to improve performance by a lot. in my calendar app, I doubled my FPS from 30 to 60 by building the `CalendarDayCell`s using a stateless widget instead of a function.

Answer (score 4):

This is something you can't control sometimes, I faced this situation where an old android phone showed it skipped 180 frames where as a new phone said it skipped 25.