# "Too many frames skipped" in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

My app is constantly showing the warning of this app is doing too much work on its main thread. Flutter clean doesn't help. Why does this warning triggers at the first point and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/58153477/5990125 ?

Comment: Yeah, it does. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Skipped x frames! The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. What does this error signify and how to solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58152545/skipped-x-frames-the-application-may-be-doing-too-much-work-on-its-main-thread)